# Move files from Azure File Storage to Dropbox using Powershell/AzCopy

Tags: azure, powershell, dropbox, azcopy, azure-storage-files

I am trying to move files from a folder in Azure File storage to a folder in the Dropbox. I am not sure how can this be achievable with PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

If by dropbox you mean a local folder on your workstation you can just pull files from Azure Storage with something like `Get-AzStorageBlobContent` or `Get-AzStorageFileContent` and then move them to the dropbox folder with `Move-Item`. If you mean talking to the dropbox rest api you can follow some articles online:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$SourceFilePath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$TargetFilePath
)

$arg = '{ "path": "' + $TargetFilePath + '", "mode": "add", "autorename": true, "mute": false }'
$authorization = "Bearer " + (get-item env:DropBoxAccessToken).Value

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", $authorization)
$headers.Add("Dropbox-API-Arg", $arg)
$headers.Add("Content-Type", 'application/octet-stream')

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload -Method Post -InFile $SourceFilePath -Headers $headers
```

https://laurentkempe.com/2016/04/07/Upload-files-to-DropBox-from-PowerShell/